# elasticsearch plugin state synchronization between nodes

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to write a plugin for elasticsearch (the cluster is running in amazon cloud). It will have a rest endpoint to start some process.
For example, I start the plugin process by hitting *http:node**1**url/_myplugin/start* and then I hit *http:node**2**url/_myplugin/start*. I don't want the plugin process to start on the node2. It should check if it is already running on any node and if it is, just do nothing. Is there a way to achive it using elasticsearch built-in features? Something like a distributed storage.